# Shared volume of 1 container into another container in Kubernates

Tags: kubernetes, splunk

I am stuck on a scenario where I have to get the log folder of container 1 into 2nd container. I have found a solution in which we will create a emptyDir directory.

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: app
    image: app-image
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8080
    volumeMounts:
    - name: logs
      mountPath: /var/log/app/
  - name: uf
    image: splunk/splunkuniversalforwarder
    ...
    volumeMounts:
    - name: logs
      mountPath: /var/log/app/
  volumes:
  - name: logs
    emptyDir: {}
```

But in my situation I want to share /usr/var/log/tomcat/ of 1st container into /var/log/message. This is because splunkUF image will monitor /var/log/app/. so I want to share the log folder of different apps, be it  /var/log/app/tomcat or /var/log/messages but at one same location with splunk container /var/log/app/.

I can run copy command to get the log 1 time but how to get the logs continuously?

Comment: Which version of kubernetes are you using?

Comment: I am using latest but does it make any difference? So that I document the version for my reference

Comment: emptyDir is not good because it will be deleted once the pod is re-assigned.
Also, are you using `Volumes` or `PersistentVolumes`? I asked for a version because there are some things in beta that might help you but it ain't easy. Example:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#mount-propagation

Comment: @UroshT. I am not using beta. So what could be my best options apart for the one present in beta?

Comment: @gamechanger17, Have you considered to set remote logging via `rsyslog` and catch logs in `/var/log/messages` like described [here](https://devops.profitbricks.com/tutorials/configure-remote-logging-with-rsyslog/)? There is also solution for [Tomcat](https://www.badllama.com/content/tomcat-7-logging-syslog-log4j).

Answer (score 2):

I don't see an issue here.
you can mount the same volume at a different location in each container.

According to your description this should be something like this:

```
spec:
  containers:
  - name: app
    image: app-image
    ...
    volumeMounts:
    - name: logs
      mountPath: /usr/var/log/tomcat/
  - name: uf
    image: splunk/splunkuniversalforwarder
    ...
    volumeMounts:
    - name: logs
      mountPath: /var/log/app/
  volumes:
  - name: logs
    emptyDir: {}
```

Comment: Yes that is the issue. but I don't see the logs in /var/log/app/ location if I go inside the uf container.

Comment: And you do see them in /usr/var/log/tomcat/ in the tomcat one?

Comment: Now I can see the logs on the shared volume but Splunkuf is not forwarding the logs to the server. I have created a new thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53669208/splunkuf-is-not-forwarding-logs-from-the-kubernates-container

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `PersistentVolumeClaim` or `PersistentVolume`, I got bad news because the access modes are pretty limited. The one you would want is `ReadWriteMany` but it has a really limited support ATM. See more info [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes).

You could do with [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath) however it has limitations of having to share a node host which not might be a desirable behaviour. I believe that something that would best suit your case would be [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#downwardapi).